# Sending arguments to Kivy.app.on_start function

Tags: python, kivy

I have some code that goes like this (MRE):

```
from kivy.app import App

    def my_function(*arguments):
       *some actions with App.root*

MyApp = App()
MyApp.on_start = my_function(some arguments)
MyApp.run()
```

It returns

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '*what I'm trying to access*'
```

Playing around a little bit I learnt that the problem is with me sending arguments when I'm assigning

```
MyApp.on_start = my_function(some arguments)
```

I have been trying multiple solutions, such as using

```
setattr(MyApp, 'on_start', my_function(some arguments))
```

and assigning to the

```
MyApp.run(some arguments)
```

call, but nothing works.
What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Post a full example. Why are you even trying to set on_start to some external function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this using `partial`:

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App


def my_function(*arguments):
    print('in my_function')
    for arg in arguments:
        print('\t', arg)

MyApp = App()
MyApp.on_start = partial(my_function, 'abba', 'dabba')
MyApp.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting the `on_start` function of the `App` class to call your `my_function` class?

```
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        self.my_function('foo','bar')

    def my_function(self, *args):
        print(args)

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Except for there are multiple functions, and which one will be called on_start depends on backend before running the app.
I know it's not in the MRE but I don't think it should be in there as it is not directly related to the problem.

Comment: Couldn't you just have some logic inside the `on_start` function to tell which function to call afterward?